# No visibility outside batch function when setting variables inside it

Tags: function, batch-file, cmd

I don't know what the problem is with this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET images=./images/
SET cdr=%CD%
SET result=noval

CD %images%
SET images=
:: Density
SET dpi=300

:: Process SVG
FOR %%x IN (%images%*.svg) DO (
  CALL:testFun %%~nx result
  echo res "%result%"
  IF [%result%]==[process] (
    ECHO Converting %%x
    inkscape -d %dpi% -A %images%%%~nx.pdf %images%%%x
  ) ELSE ( ECHO - Skiping %%x, file is uptodate.)
)

:: Process BMP, JPG, PNG, and TIFF
FOR %%x IN (%images%*.jpg,%images%*.bmp,%images%*.png,%images%*.tiff) DO (
  CALL:testFun %%~nx result
  echo res "%result%"
  IF [%result%]==[process] (
    ECHO Converting %%x
    inkscape -d %dpi% -A %images%%%~nx.pdf %images%%%x 
  ) ELSE ( ECHO - Skiping %%x, file is uptodate.)
)



:: Process EPS
FOR %%x IN (%images%*.eps) DO (
  CALL :testFun %%~nx result
  echo res "%result%"
  IF [%result%]==[process] (
    ECHO Converting %%x
    epstopdf --outfile=%images%%%~nx.pdf %images%%%x
  ) ELSE ( ECHO - Skiping %%x, file is uptodate.)
)

CD %cdr%
ECHO.&PAUSE&GOTO:EOF

::Functions

:testFun
SET "file=%1"
FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /Od /B "%file%.*"') DO (SET newest=%%~xf)
echo * Newest file for %file%: %newest%
IF [%newest%]==[.pdf] (echo noprocessing
GOTO :noprocess) ELSE (echo processing
GOTO :process)
:noprocess
SET result=noprocess
GOTO :endfun
:process
SET result=process
:endfun
GOTO:EOF
```

The idea is that it should process different images in a directory, only if the images (source) are newer than the resultant PDF (output).

However, there are several problems that I don't know why they are happening.

- First, the first loop uses the value of `result` and print `noval` all the time, and it looks like it is skipping the function call. But then, the same way of calling works on the second and third loop.
- Second, in the other loops (in which the first problem doesn't occur) the value of `result`, that is changed inside the function, is not there. Like the scope is different. However, I'm using it as a global variable, right? I test this version using `set local` and passing the variable as reference but nothing work.

What I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code runs as it should. What you are not aware of is that `cmd` expands environment variables when *parsing* a command. A command in this case can be a complete `for` including the block. So after parsing it no variables remain in it, only text. Which means if you change a variable *within* a block *and use it in the same block* you won't see the change.

To resolve this you can use delayed expansion which ensures that variables are expanded directly prior to running a single line (even within blocks) and thus mitigate this problem. Add the following at the top of your batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then use `!result!` instead of `%result%` to access the variables' values.